# Why "array1.reduce(reducer)" in the coding paragraph use '.reduce' after 'array1'? It seems that array1 doest not contain reduce this object

Tags: javascript, methods, reduce

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (previous, current) => previous + current;


// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
// expected output: 15
```

When running the above codes, it gives 10 and then 15

Comment: The output and the expected output is the same. I don't get what is your problem?

Comment: The code is correct. the output is expected. I just want to know why arry1 can take reduce this method and how it works to get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with how it gets executed

```
Your Example:
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (previous, current) => previous + current;

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));`enter code here`
// expected output: 15
```

As you are saying why it does not get reduced when you apply .reduce for first time.

so, when you apply .reduce it does not change original array but return newly created array.So reducer is applied on newly created array and not on original array(array1)

So you can check output with following code,it might clear your doubt :

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => 
{
 console.log("Data is"+accumulator +' '+ currentValue); 
 return accumulator + currentValue;
}

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
// expected output: 15
```

where accumulator is value which it return from reducer function.
      currentValue is current value of your array.